# Jenkins not triggering pipeline build on successful github webhook

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I have setup Jenkins and integrated with Github, and I am able to trigger builds on "Freestyle Projects" from a github webhook, however I have been unsuccessful in triggering one using the "Pipeline project".

In the logs (/log/all), I can see that my Jenkins instance is receiving the PushEvent from Github:

```
Aug 17, 2020 8:29:43 PM INFO org.jenkinsci.plugins.github.webhook.subscriber.DefaultPushGHEventSubscriber onEvent
Received PushEvent for https://github.com/xxx/xxx from xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx ⇒ https://xip.io:9090/github-webhook/
```

However it does not "Poke" the project like the "Freestyle" project does.
I have checked the Githook hook trigger for the project:

[image]

And the pipeline is setup as:
[image]

After setting it all up, I triggered a manual job which completed successfully, afterwards I comitted and pushed new code to Master, saw the webhook triggering in Github and in the Jenkins Log.

Am I missing a unique step for the Pipeline build?

Running Jenkins v 2.235.4

Comment: Did you configure the Github plugin in jenkins? Have you defined credentials for Github?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I checked off the "Lightweight Checkout" in the last section of the Pipeline, ran a manual build which fixed the issue. Builds are now triggered from Github webhook.

[image]

I did not have to setup Github Credentials in the Github Plugin to make this work.

Comment: Thanks for updating the question, could you mark it as answered?